# Why do usernames end in $ in my Active Directory password filter DLL?

Tags: c++, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a custom Active Directory password filter DLL.

On a two-domain DC (Windows Server 2012 R2), the password filter sometimes receives the usernames with a dollar sign (`$`).

1. A user's account name is `JSMITH`.
2. The password filter DLL reports that `JSMITH$` changed their password.

Why is this happening?

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
    _In_ ULONG RelativeId,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword
)
{
    // Set up process creation arguments
    STARTUPINFO startupInformation;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    ZeroMemory(&startupInformation, sizeof(startupInformation));
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    // Prepare arguments
    std::wstring arguments = std::wstring(UserName->Buffer)
        + L" "
        + std::wstring(NewPassword->Buffer);

    // ...
```

Comment: Possibly an ancient remnant of when one of Microsoft's programming languages used `$` as a string terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time the username (aka the [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) attribute in AD) automatically contains a `$` at the end is for computer accounts. And [computer accounts do actually have passwords](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/02/15/machine-account-password-process-2/), so it could just be reporting that a computer updated its password.

I guessing maybe that `JSMITH$` was just made up example, since `JSMITH` sounds like a user account.

However, it is possible for you to explicitly put a `$` at the end of a user's username, if you wanted to.

Comment: That's the odd thing. In this case, they actually *are* human users' `sAMAccountName`s except for the suffixed `$`. For example (`JSMITH` is anonymized, but otherwise this is just like an account I'm looking at right now), the password filter DLL logs `JSMITH$`. I query `(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=*JSMITH*))` and I only get back `JSMITH`.

Comment: Using `(objectCategory=user)` in your query would exclude any computer account if there was one. If you search for just `(sAMAccountName=JSMITH*)`, do you find any other results?

Comment: D'oh. You're absolutely right. I wasn't familiar with how the domain was set up, but apparently the computer accounts have the same names as the users they belong to.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) But that is a weird practice.